# Getting Error "can not GET/ " for trying to preview lite-server and using only command prompt in node.js

Tags: node.js, package.json, npm-start

I am learning a course about bootstrap 4 in Coursera. I got some instructions to preview lite-server on the browser by command prompt but when I try to start the lite-server from the command prompt like - npm start it does show the message can not GET/ I tried to find a solution about it but all I got some codes as a solution like this

```
 app.get('/api/courses',  (req, res) => { ... }
)
```

But I don't think so I have a file like this. I am just working with cmd.this is my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "git-test-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a description ",
  "main": "index-1.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start":"npm run lite",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
      "lite":"lite-server"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://Sheikh_Araf@bitbucket.org/Sheikh_Araf/git-test.git"
  },
  "author": "Sheikh Araf",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/Sheikh_Araf/git-test#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.5.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: `app.get('/',  (req, res) => { ... })`  this may help

Comment: But I don't know where to put this?

Comment: doesn't work it says error can not GET/